# Solving $y'-\frac y x=0$ with integrating factor

Tags: integration, differential

How do you solve $y'-\frac y x=0$   the answer should be $y=ex$  but I can't get to that point. I tried using the integrating factor but I can't get it to add up.

Comment: Do you mean $y=ex$ or $y=e^x$ ?

Comment: I think it is $y=ex$

Answer (score 2):

You may have made a mistake in computing an integrating factor, but one such factor is $ 1/x$. Multiplying the equation by $1/x$ and using product rule, we obtain $(y/x)' = 0$. So $y/x = C$, where $C$ is a constant. In other words, $y = Cx$.